# Subdivided icosahedron - how to find the nearest vertex to an arbitrary point

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have an application that creates an approximation to sphere by subdividing an icosahedron. The Cartesian vertex coordinates are converted to spherical coordinates so that all vertices sit on the surface of a unit sphere.

What I need to do next is find the nearest vertex to an arbitrary point on the surface of the sphere. I have come up with two simple algorithms...

1. Brute force search - will be OK for a small number of vertices, but will be excessive for finer subdivisions.
2. Sorted / Indexed search - sort the vertices into some form of order by azimuth and inclination and then create a rough index to speed up a brute force search by limiting its scope.

I was wondering if there was a more subtle, and hopefully higher performing algorithm that I can use instead of one of the two above.

**Update 1:** I have just recalled that for another part of the application the vertices store information about their neighbours. My new algorithm is

1. Pick an arbitrary start vertex. Find which of its neighbours has a smaller distance to the point to locate. Use this neighbour as the new start vertex. Repeat until none of the vertex's neighbours has a smaller distance to the point. This vertex is the closest to the point.

Comment: A not-too-hard way to find a good starting vertex:  Overlay a 100x100x100 grid on your sphere, and for each grid cell, pre-compute the closest vertex to the center of the cell.  Now, given an arbitrary point, look up the cell that the point is in, and use the pre-computed closest vertex as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Scanning through the responses, I think I may be off base, but what you're after is simple. I think.

Since you're dealing with just points that sit on the sphere, you can just drop a line from the vertex to the center of the sphere, drop another line from the arbitrary point to the center and solve for the angle created between them. Smaller is better. The easiest and cheapest way I think would be the dot product. The angle basically falls out of it. Here's a link about it: http://www.kynd.info/library/mathandphysics/dotProduct_01/
For testing them, I would suggest picking a vertex, testing it, then testing its neighbors. It SHOULD always be in the direction of the smallest neighbor (angle should always decrease as you get closer to the vertex you're after)

Anyhow, I hope that's what you're after. 
Oh, and I came across this page while looking for your subdivision algorithm. Hard to find; if you could post a link to it I think it would help out a lot more than just myself.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions is to build BSP tree for vertices: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning

Answer (score 0):

If the icosahedron has one vertex at the north pole and the opposite vertex at the south pole then there are 2 groups each of 5 vertices which are in planes parallel to the equator.  With a little geometry I figure that these planes are at N/S 57.3056° (decimals, not dd.mmss).  This divides your icosahedron into 4 latitude zones;

- anything north (south) of 28.6528° is closest to the vertex at the nearer pole;
- anything between the equator and north (south) 28.6528° is closer to one of the 5 vertices in that zone.

I'm working this as a navigator would, arcs measured in degrees and denoted north and south; if you prefer a more mathematical convention you can translate this all to your version of spherical coordinates quite easily.

I suspect, though I haven't coded it, that checking the distance to 5 vertices and selecting the nearest will be quicker than more sophisticated approaches based on partitioning the surface of the sphere into the projections of the faces of the icosahedron, or projecting the points on the sphere back onto the icosahedron and working the problem in that coordinate system.

For example, the approach you suggest in your update 1 will require the computation of the distance to 6 vertices (the first, arbitrarily chosen one and its 5 neighbours) at least.

It doesn't matter (if you only want to know which vertex is nearest) whether you calculate distances in Cartesian or spherical coordinates.  However, calculation in Cartesian coordinates avoids a lot of calls to trigonometric functions.

If, on the other hand, you haven't arranged your icosahedron with vertices at the poles of your sphere, well, you should have !

Comment: I think I may not have made the question clear enough - the icosahedron is subdivided to approximate the sphere. Once I'm happy with my algorithms I plan to increase the number of nodes to over 600000 and offload the number crunching to a GPU. However, I do have vertices at the poles!

Comment: In that case, have a look at http://www.geog.ucsb.edu/~good/papers/162.pdf and google around for similar ideas.